# Is libsvm accurate?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, libsvm

With StompChicken's corrections (I miscomputed one dot product, ugh!) the answer appears to be yes. I have since tested the same problem using a precomputed kernel with the same correct results. If you are using libsvm StompChickens clear, organized computations are a very nice check.

**Original Question:** 
I am about to start using precomputed kernels in libSVM. I had noticed 
[Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474460/precomputed-kernels-with-libsvm-in-python) to a question and I thought it would be wise to confirm that libsvm gave correct answers. I started with non-precomputed kernels, just a simple linear kernel with 2 classes and three data points in 3 dimensional space. I used the data

```
1 1:3 2:1 3:0
2 1:3 2:3 3:1
1 1:7 3:9
```

The model file generated by a call to `svm-train -s 0 - t 0` contains

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type linear
nr_class 2
total_sv 3
rho -1.53951
label 1 2
nr_sv 2 1
SV
0.4126650675419768 1:3 2:1 3:0 
0.03174528241667363 1:7 3:9 
-0.4444103499586504 1:3 2:3 3:1
```

However when I compute the solution by hand that is not what I get. Does anyone know whether libsvm suffers from errors or can anyone compare notes and see whether they get the same thing libsvm does?

The coefficients `a1`, `a2`, `a3` returned by libsvm are should be the values that make

```
a1 + a2 + a3 - 5*a1*a1 + 12*a1*a2 - 21*a1*a3 - 19*a2*a2/2 + 21*a2*a3 - 65*a3*a3
```

as large as possible with the restrictions that 
`a1 + a3 = a2`
and each of `a1`, `a2`, `a3` is required to lie between 0 and 1 (the default value of C).

The above model file says the answer is

```
a1 = .412665...
a2 = .444410...
a3 = .031745...
```

But one just has to substitute `a2 = a1 + a3` into the big formula above and confirm both partial derivatives are zero to see if this solution is correct (since none of `a1`,`a2`,`a3` is 0 or 1) but they are not zero.

Am I doing something wrong, or is libsvm giving bad results?  (I am hoping I am doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LibSVM is a very widely used library and I highly doubt anything is drastically wrong with the code. That said, I think it's great that there are people who are paranoid enough to actually check it for correctness - well done!

The solution seems correct according to the working that I give below. What I mean by that is it satisfies the [KKT conditions](http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/ebooks/html/csa/node222.html) (15.29). It also true that the partial derivatives of the dual vanish at the solution.

Here's my working...

```
x1 = (3,1,0)  x2 = (3,3,1)  x3 = (7,0,9)
y1 = -1       y2 = 1        y3 = -1

K = [10   12   21]
    [12   19   30]
    [21   30  130]

L_dual = a1 + a2 + a3 -5a1^2 + 12a1a2 - 21a1a3 - (19/2)a2^2 + 30a2a3 - 65a3^2)

a1 = 0.412  a2 = 0.4444  a3 = 0.0317

Checking KKT:
y1.f(x1) = y1 * (y1*a1*K(x1,x1) + y2*a2*K(x1,x2) + y3*a3*k(x1,x3) - rho)
         = rho + 10*a1 + 21*a3 - 12*a2
         ~= 1
(Similar for the x2 and x3)

Substituting a2 = a1 + a3 into L_dual:
L_dual = 2a1 + 2a3 - 2.5a1^2 + 2a1a3 - 44.5a3^2
dL/da1 = 2 - 5a1 + 2a3 = 0
dL/da3 = 2 + 2a1 - 89a3 = 0
```